# Which of LBA or TM would you choose to express the given language and why?

Tags: automata

Both Linear Bound Automata (LBA) and Turing machine (TM) can be used to express the language accepted by below Finite Automaton (FA). Which of LBA or TM would you choose to express the given language and why? Justify your decision with logical reasons.
[image]

Comment: Neither, because it is expressible as a DFA. Which is a weaker model than either.
What are you trying to optimise for in the decision? Using weakest model of sufficent strength? Simplest program?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour, if you have not yet done so. When
posting a question, make sure to give enough context, and show how you
tried to answer it on your own, so as to be very precise regarding
your problem. This helps better answers. In particular, where does that question come from? What context? Are there other criteria to meet or goal to attain?

Comment: I don't see the point of the question. Linear bounded automata and Turing machines are models of computation. A language can be defined in any sufficiently powerful model of computation. If you actually wanted a computer to recognize the language, you'd write a program in a programming language.

Comment: @DavidRicherby One may want to downvote the asker for not giving the context of his question, and not giving his own view of the question. But, imho, he obviously did not make it up, and he is probably reporting it faithfully. Hence giving a proper answer to this question may be useful to users of the site. The point is, for what I can guess, that it is really a devious question, aiming at seeing reactions and knowledge of the person who is being asked. My view is that CS site users may also be interested in learning about such questions.

Comment: @babou I was voting and commenting based purely on the quality of the question, independently of whether the asker made it up themself or is reporting a question that somebody else asked them. And if you think the point of the question is people's reactions to it, that isn't computer science.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well ... policies are a bit inconsistent, imho. I sometimes would wish SE to be stricter on scientific issues ... given the nonsense I see on occasion, or factually wrong statements. Then this is about understanding computer science and some automata issues, and how to deal with problems. It may have a meta character, but it is definitely CS. Another point is that the question would be perfectly acceptable on a harder problem. It is the triviality of it that you are objecting to.

Comment: @babou I'm not objecting to triviality: I've not actually checked what the language is. My objection is exactly as I laid out in my first comment: the question simply doesn't make sense. It's essentially asking, "Here's a language and a bunch of models of computation in which it's definable. Which one would you prefer to prove and why?"

Comment: @jal Pari You may see here why **your question might fare better if you had explained precisely why you need help**.

Comment: You just edited ... ignoring all  comments and advice and adding no useful information. What do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

I expect this is an exercise to check how you can read and analyze a
finite state automaton, and possibly some other knowledge.

The question is absurd since a FA is trivially expressible as a LBA or
a TM, so that the question makes little sense, even more so because a
LBA is a TM using linearly bounded tape, which is obviously the case
for a FA, where the tape is limited to the size of the input.

But what is more, is that the simplest way to represent the language
is to enumerate all its strings, all four of them.

$$L=\{a,abb,abba,abbaab\}$$

It may be that this set has some special property, but I do not know it.

Of course, I do not want to spoil the fun of seeing why $L$ is composed of only 4 strings.

> Look well at states 1 and 9.